# Parameters query with Promise (from Observable)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

Here's my `ProspectAPIsService`

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class ProspectAPIsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getOneProspect(nome) {
  return this.http.get('assets/mocks/prospect.json').toPromise();
  }
}
```

I'm fetching data by reading a dummy json file. Here's the data in that file.

```
[
    {"nome":"Dam", "cog":"prova"},
    {"nome":"luc", "cog":"prova2"}
]
```

I have to use Promises over Observable. I really don't know how to use the parameter 'name' that I'm getting in `getOneProspect` method for filtering the result data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, that should be something a `REST`ful API should do which you will request for using an `HTTP` method(`GET`/`POST`). In that case, you'd pass the name as a query parameter(in case of `GET`) or as a request payload(in case of `POST`). And the API would respond back, with the filtered data.

But since you're `GET`ting a Mock JSON file, this is something that you'll have to do in the service itself.

So, specifically for your use case, chain a `map` operator to whatever is returned from the call to the `get` method of `http`. Do the filtering in that `map`. And then, since `map` returns an `Observable`, you can chain a `toPromise` to it. And that should do the trick.

Assuming that you'll be getting `users` as an array from your prospect.json file , this is how it'll translate to code:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProspectAPIsService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }

   public getOneProspect(nome) {
       return this.http.get('assets/mocks/prospect.json')
        .map(users => {
            console.log(users);
            return users.filter(user => user.nome === nome)[0];
        })
        .toPromise();
   }
}
```

Comment: But map doesn't exist on type Observable

Comment: You'll have to `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: And for the filter method?

Comment: Filter is a build in method on array type in JavaScript.

Comment: It gave me the same error for filter: "filter doesn't exist on type Object"

Comment: Log users and check which key inside that object has your prospect users array. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Promise, you can use the `.then(data)` chained function, and there you can perform your filters.  This is untested code, but you could do the following:

```
getOneProspect(input)
   .then((data: any[]) => {
       const prospect = // filter data here
       return prospect;
}
```

As a best practice, you'll want to replace the `any[]` with an array of type `prospect` if you have defined that in your code.

I hope this helps!